# how to make keyboard to press ctrl key after every 5 minutes?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse, xdotool, click-packages

I have the `xdotool` installed and would like it to:

- press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key every 5 minutes
- scroll a window up and down every 5 minutes
- make a mouse click every 5 minutes

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Install xdotool.
Should be in your linux repository.

```
while sleep 300; do
   xdotool key Ctrl click 4 click 5 click 1
done
```

In sequence the above causes control key to press and release
click mouse button 4 (scroll up one unit)
click mouse button 5 (scroll down one unit)
click mouse button 1 (left mouse button)

If you want something more specific like control clicks,  then you may need to give more information.  xdotool can also move the mouse pointer around send text, and do a lot of other things as well.